# How to: Force users to focus a winform before selecting something from it

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a project that uses WinForms, and I am running into concurrency problems when users click controls on a `Form` while it isn't the active window. My forms refresh whenever a user activates them to prevent them from showing old/dirty info, but if they click a button on an inactive `Form` the data doesn't get refreshed, which can cause a problem.

I know some programs in windows force you to select the window before you can preform any other actions, is there a way to do this in my VB.NET program?

Comment: `it doesn't get a chance to refresh it's data` - why? It does activate when its button is clicked, doesn't it?

Comment: Do you have some async processing there? So, when someone clicks something the async stuff is not done yet, and you get exceptions/misbehaviours?

Comment: You can make variable status, and make it true while you refresh anything, after finish set the status to false. And in your button click, if the status is true, do nothing, but if it is false, perform as normal

Comment: Its awfully vague, sounds like the Click event of that button is doing something very naughty.  Like hanging up the main thread for far too long, not enough concurrency.  User input is always handled before any pending repaints.  Put Me.Update() as the first statement in the event handler to get the repaint before the code goes off in the woods.

Answer (score 0):

This code run in my test, but some issues that must be handled to run as our need:

```
Dim mystts As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form2_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    'here your process, unfortunately this will be performed too after messagebox close back to form2
    'for example the process are:
    For myCnt As Integer = 1 To 4000
        Debug.Print("Test") 'This only for waiting
    Next
    mystts = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Deactivate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
    'we must define the other criteria for make mystts=true, for example if 
    'we call messageBox.show, we can pass out from this for example we have msgFlag
    'before call messageBox set msgFlag=true and after it set  msgFlag=false
    'and here you add: if msgFlag=true then exit sub
    mystts = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'if we click this button and myStts=true, the next process will wait until process in form activate finish
    MsgBox("this My Process, run after form2 activated and process finish")
End Sub
```